# I need an XSD in which either a combination of 2 elements OR 1 other element is mandatory

Tags: xsd

I have an XML that supplies a Reference number. It should have either HeaderNumber and LineNumber OR ExternalReference. Both (all three elements) are allowed as well.
I can get the first part right with groups and a choice, but how do I allow (and not force) for all elements to be present?

I have this XSD to force all elements to be present:

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:group name="InternalReference">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="HeaderNumber" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="LineNumber" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="Reference">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:group ref="InternalReference"/>
      <xs:element name="ExternalReference"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:complexType name="message">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:group ref="Reference" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Message" type="message"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and this XSD to have either of the references present:

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:group name="InternalReference">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="HeaderNumber" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="LineNumber" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="Reference">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:group ref="InternalReference"/>
      <xs:element name="ExternalReference"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:complexType name="message">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="Reference" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Message" type="message"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I would appreciate any help very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround. It's not the optimum solution, but very workable.

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="ExternalReference" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:group name="InternalReference">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="HeaderNumber" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="LineNumber" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element ref="ExternalReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="External">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="ExternalReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="Reference">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:group ref="InternalReference"/>
      <xs:group ref="External"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:complexType name="message">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="Reference" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Message" type="message"/>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm still hoping for a better way.